# Magento - how to create new product type based on bundle product

Tags: magento-1.7

I have problem about how to create new product type based on Bundle product.

I create my module and extends Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type in NameSpace/ModuleName/Model/Product/Type/myproducttype.php. So if I going to admin and create my new product type, product look like simple product not bundle product.

in my config.xml is

```
<catalog>
  <product>
    <type>
      <formula translate="label" module="bank">
        <label>Formula Product</label>
        <model>bank/product_type_formula</model>
        <price_model>bank/product_type_formula_price</price_model>
      </formula>
    </type>
  </product>
</catalog>
```

in my Formula.php is

```
<?php

class xxxx_Bank_Model_Product_Type_Formula extends Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type
{
public function isVirtual($product = null)
{
    return true;
}
}

?>
```

I don't know why. can you help me ?

Answer (score 4):

The main reason is because you are missing the `<composite>1</composite>` tag, however, you are missing a lot more directive that make up the definition of a bundle product.

from `app/code/core/mage/Bundle/etc/config.xml`

```
<type>
   <bundle translate="label" module="bundle">
       <label>Bundle Product</label>
       <model>bundle/product_type</model>
       <composite>1</composite>
       <allowed_selection_types>
          <simple/>
          <virtual/>
       </allowed_selection_types>
       <price_model>bundle/product_price</price_model>
                        <index_data_retreiver>bundle/catalogIndex_data_bundle</index_data_retreiver>
        <index_priority>40</index_priority>
        <price_indexer>bundle/indexer_price</price_indexer>
        <stock_indexer>bundle/indexer_stock</stock_indexer>
    </bundle>
</type>
```

Then you also need to specify what select types.

again, from the bundle `config.xml`

```
<options>
            <bundle>
                <types>
                    <select translate="label" module="bundle">
                        <label>Drop-down</label>
                    </select>
                    <radio translate="label" module="bundle">
                        <label>Radio Buttons</label>
                    </radio>
                    <checkbox translate="label" module="bundle">
                        <label>Checkbox</label>
                    </checkbox>
                    <multi translate="label" module="bundle">
                        <label>Multiple Select</label>
                    </multi>
                </types>
            </bundle>
        </options>
```

Use the core bundle module `app/code/core/mage/Bundle/` as a reference/starting point, and systematically copy over and refactor the parts that you need

Comment: still can't solve this problem, need more detail please

Comment: Need more input. Can you update what you now have please.

Comment: I just post new reply, please consider for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: anyone can help ?